# Spring ComponentScan package-structure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, component-scan

My application contains the following classes among others:
SpringMainApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo"})
class com.foo.appl.SpringMainApplication {
... some code...
}
```

An interface that should be used to autowire a field:

```
interface com.foo.bar.ClassToAutowire {
}
```

And another class that uses said interface for a field:

```
@Component
class com.foo.appl.pack.ImplementationClass {

@Autowired
ClassToAutowire autoClass;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
public void startStuff() {
  // do something...
  }

}
```

But the field won't autowire:

> Field autoClass in com.foo.appl.pack.ImplementationClass required a
>   bean of type 'com.foo.bar.ClassToAutowire' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.foo.bar.ClassToAutowire' in your
>   configuration.

I guess Spring doesn't like my package-structure?

```
com.foo.bar.ClassToAutowire
com.foo.appl.SpringMainApplication
com.foo.appl.pack.ImplementationClass
```

Does the `@SpringBootApplication` have to be in the root package and all components must be in subpackages? If so, how do I solve my "problem", because the `ClassToAutowire` comes from an imported JAR.

When changing the `basePackge` to `com.foo.bar` the application starts, but then the scheduled method won't run.

Thanks

Comment: Put your `SpringMainApplication` in `com.foo` or add a `@ComponentScan("com.foo")` onto your `SpringMainApplication`.

Comment: While putting `SpringMainApplication` in `com.foo` solves my problem, I would like to keep my package-structure as is...
`@ComponentScan("com.foo")` is already added to the SpringMainApplication.

Comment: It is a best practice to your your starting point in the top-level package. As stated in my comment if you really don't want that (which has several disadvantages especially when starting to use more frameworks) add `@ComponentScan("com.foo")` but this will for instance not auto detect Spring Data repositories, JPA entities etc. you will need a lot of additional configuration which otherwise you get for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Spring Boot it by default does component scanning. This component-scanning is done starting in the same package as the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in. In your case that is `com.foo.appl` however this does not cover `com.foo.bar`.

The best practice is to put your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the most top-level package you can find, in your case that would be `com.foo`. This will scan all packages beneath it and will include the proper components.

You could also add `@ComponentScan("com.foo")` to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to let it start scanning at a different package or (`@SpringBootApplication(basePackage="com.foo")`.

If there aren't anymore components in the dependency jar you could also add a `@Bean` method to create an instance of the desired class.

```
@Bean
public ClassToAutowire classToAutowire() {
    return new ClassToAutowire();
}
```

The drawback of the second approach is that when using things like Spring Data or JPA you will also manually have to configure those (adding things like `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan`). This will grow when using/adding different frameworks, this isn't the case when you put the class in a top-level package as all packages are considered.

Answer (score 0):

*Does the @SpringBootApplication have to be in the root package and all components must be in subpackages?* No, @SpringBootApplication can be placed anywhere, but you will need to provide correct path in @ComponentScan

If implementation of ClassToAutowire class comes from external package, you will need to import spring configuration from that jar. This means define configuration class annotated with @Configuration and then import this configuration in your ImplementationClass using @Import annotation. 
Another woulb using spring auto-configuration described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You should implement *interface com.foo.bar.ClassToAutowire* and annotate the class with **@Component**

**@Component** Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.
[reference @Component documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)